# Displaying currency in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, currency

I need to display data values in US currency format. Meaning 190.8 should display as $190.80. For some reason I cant figure out how to do this. Any advice?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could explicitly specify the US culture like so:

```
string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", decimalValue)
```

The C indicates the default currency format for the specified culture, in this case exactly what you're after. If you want the US currency symbol with a continental European number format (comma instead of period) then your job would be harder of course...

Answer (score 1):

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

```
   decimal moneyvalue = 1921.39m;
    string html = String.Format("Order Total: {0:C}", moneyvalue);
    Console.WriteLine(html);
```

or

```
double value = 12345.6789;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));//CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")
// current culture is English (United States):
//       $12,345.68
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 decimal d = 190.8M;
 string displayData = d.ToString("c");
```

If your `CurrentCulture` is already US there's no need to explicitly supply it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Format("${0:n2}", 190.8m);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string usCurrency = (190.8m).ToString("c", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```