# How to show dollar amount in asp.net razor page?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I implement an asp.net core razor page application. I declare the field Budget as Money type in SQL database. If I enter 1234.50 on View page cshtml input tag, how to display it as $1,234.55 on the page?

how to get formatted currency data?

Comment: heh, they call it "bankers rounding"... (but off by a decimal)  JK... Might use this : string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", decimalValue)  Grabbed from this old thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069484/displaying-currency-in-c-sharp  also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol?view=net-7.0